# Debounced search not filtering properly in react app only on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, mobile, debouncing

So I have a react app and recently added a searchbar that debounces the value.  It works as intended on desktop in dev and prod but when attempting to use it on a mobile device, it filters all items instead of based on the input.

I use this hook for my debouncing:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function useDebounce<T>(value: T, delay?: number): T {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState<T>(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => setDebouncedValue(value), delay || 500);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, [value, delay]);

  return debouncedValue;
}

export default useDebounce;
```

and call it in a global context as such:

```
const debouncedValue = useDebounce(searchTerm, 1000);
```

I have attempted using several durations between 250 and 1000 to see if it was potentially just a mobile device needing more time to catch up but the result was the same.

Here is where the filtering takes place:

```
<div className="mt-2">
      <div>{data?.length === 0 && <p>No Items</p>}</div>
      {sortType === "All" && (
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
          <Banner>All Food Items</Banner>
          {itemsSortedAlphabetically
            ?.filter((item) => {
              if (debouncedValue === "") {
                return item;
              } else if (
                item.name.toLowerCase().includes(debouncedValue) ||
                item.brand?.toLowerCase().includes(debouncedValue)
              ) {
                return item;
              }
            })
            .map((item) => (
              <Item key={item.id} {...item} />
            ))}
        </div>
      )}
      {sortType === "Storage Area" && (
        <ItemsByStorageArea storageAreaId={storageAreaId!} />
      )}
      {sortType === "Food Type" && (
        <ItemsByFoodType
          foodTypeIds={foodTypeIds}
          foodTypesList={foodTypesList}
        />
      )}
      {sortType === "Expiring Soon" && (
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
          <Banner>Expiring Soon</Banner>
          {itemsSortedByExpiringSoon
            ?.filter((item) => {
              if (debouncedValue === "") {
                return item;
              } else if (
                item.name.toLowerCase().includes(debouncedValue) ||
                item.brand?.toLowerCase().includes(debouncedValue)
              ) {
                return item;
              }
            })
            .map((item) => (
              <Item key={item.id} {...item} />
            ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
```

As stated before it works fine when on any device either dev or online except for mobile devices.

Note:  I am not sure if it matters but I have only been able to test this on android devices.

Update:  I have printed the debouncedValue to the screen and it does show up as input so it doesn't appear to be an issue with the mobile keyboard.

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK filter should return true or false.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.   Does the if/else if block in the filtering logic not satisfy that?  The only time it does not work as intended is on mobile devices, that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my item properties name and brand had toLowerCase(), but my debouncedValue did not, and mobile keyboards automatically capitalize the first letter input.  Ooof.